# Getting an error while trying to send SS command using USAT application

Tags: gsm, sim-card, ussd, umts, sim-toolkit

I'm trying to have a USIM perform call forwarding (a.k.a call redirection) using the proactive command SEND SS (TS 31.111 sections: 6.4.11, 8.14, etc.). Unfortunately I keep getting an error from the network which I can't understand.

I'm trying the following sequence:

```
ME->USIM: 8012000018 (FETCH from the ME toward UICC)
USIM->ME: 12 (procedure byte)
USIM->ME: D01681030411008202818305000909FFAA120A25556777B49000

 D0 (proactive command) 16 (length)
 81 (command details) 03 (length) 04 (command number) 11 (SEND SS) 00 (RFU)
 82 (device identities) 02 (length) 81 (UICC) 83 (network)
 05 (alpha identifier) 00 (length)
 909FFAA120A25556777B4 (SS String = **21*0525576774#)
 9000 (OK)

ME->USIM: 801400000D (Terminal response of size 0x0D)
USIM->ME: 14 (procedure byte)
ME->USIM: 81030411000202828103023424

 81 (command details) 03 (length) 04 (command number) 11 (SEND SS) 00 (RFU)
 02 (device identities) 02 (length) 82 (ME) 81 (UICC)
 03 (Result) 02 (length) 34 (SS Return Error) 24 (???)
```

I can't figure out what '24' means.

Just to make sure I'm using a correct SS string, I activated CALL CONTROL on the USIM and dialed **21*0525576774# in the keypad. The result was as follows:

```
ME->UICC: 80C200001C (Envelope of length 0x1C)
UICC->ME: C2 (procedure byte)
ME->UICC: D41A020282810909FFAA120A25556777B4130924F51027D078CF0013

 D4 (envelope) 1A (length)
 02 (device identities) 02 (length) 82 (ME) 81 (UICC) 
 09 (send ss) 09 (length) FFAA120A25556777B4 (SS string)
 13 (location information) 09 (length) 24F51027D078CF0013 (not relevant)

USIM->ME: 9000 (OK)
```

As you can see, the SS string is identical. When the ME sends it it seems to work (call forwarding is activated) yet when I try to send it from the UICC to the network I get the error '3424'.

I've searched through the specs (TS 31.111, TS 22.030 and even TS 24.080) but didn't find even the tiniest lead as to what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Cheers,

Nir.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs due to timer management(Action in contradiction with the current timer state) becouse
0x34-> Means SS Return Error
0x24-> Means Action in contradiction with the current timer state.